# Does <600V Research Environment require safety training?

Tags: safety

If working in a lab on electronics with capacitors and stored energy, I understand there can be hazards with energy discharge, electrical shock, burns etc. We have voltages up to 400V.

Is formal training for this environment required? Is there a good professional training program (ideally not a full course, just a few hours or an afternoon) that you would recommend for college graduates entering this environment? Most everything I have seen is focused on Distribution type work as opposed to lab electronics hazards and thus does not seem worth the full day course.

Comment: Required by whom?

Comment: Required by whom? Legally? That would probably depend on your jurisdiction. I only offer my opinion. A shock from 400V could easily be fatal. I would not expose anyone to such a risk unless I had confidence in their understanding of electricity and their judgment in handling it. Formal training might give me such confidence.

Comment: It's required by my employer.  HV lab safety, First aid, & CPR.  But at least in the US, I don't think there's a regulatory requirement for specific training in an R&D environment, it's left to the employer to provide.

Comment: Even 120V can be fatal, which is why we have GFCI in the US/Canada (and RCD in most other places). The problem is compounded in a lab because capacitors and other things can result in high current and voltage levels isolated (and therefore not protected) from the main AC supply. So yeah, safety training would be a very good idea.

Comment: @JohnD D Do you know who administered your training or how I could find the course?

Comment: @Hearth I am wondering requirements by law.  If I pick a training I would want it to comply with any actual laws regarding what training is required. If certain trainings are legally required I would administer those.

Comment: @MaxwellEE Our training is developed internally, except for the first-aid and CPR which a contractor administers.  I don't have the name of the company, but it shouldn't be too hard to find a provider.

Comment: @MaxwellEE Requirements by law are going to depend on where you're located, as well as the nature of the research. If the research you're doing involves exposing humans (or other animals) to the high voltage, for instance, requirements will be much more stringent and probably covered by a different regulatory agency.

Comment: I’m voting to close because this is not an electronic design question; you may however find useful advice on other Stacks such as Legal or Workplace.